# newbie objective c pointer question "*" syntax

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I'm often getting warnings about passing the wrong pointer types to functions and I just want to once and for all understand this properly.

What is the difference between these two?

```
CFURLRef *ref=(CFURLRef *)sourceURLArray[0];

CFURLRef ref=(CFURLRef )sourceURLArray[0];
```

Does the first one actually reference the memory address of the object in the array?
Does the second one make a copy of it?

The main style of code that I'm pursuing at the moment is to have an array of values or objects. I want to be able to use these values, passing them to other functions, without altering the originals.

Leading from that the 2 function declarations I have been trying are the following.

```
- (void) loadAudioFileIntoMemory:(CFURLRef *)address channel:(int) value row:(int) value2;

- (void) loadAudioFileIntoMemory:(CFURLRef )address channel:(int) value row:(int) value2;
```

What would the difference be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CFURLRef is already a pointer -- it's [declared](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html) as:

```
typedef const struct __CFURL *CFURLRef;
```

In general, you will want to use the type `CFURLRef` *without the ** when declaring a variable to hold a URL.  Most (or all?) of the Core Foundation objects are defined this way, and you can assume a type that ends in `Ref` is a pointer.

So if you want an array of 10 URLs, you would write something like:

```
CFURLRef sourceURLArray[10];
//... populate the array.
// Get a particular URL out of the array:
CFURLRef ref = sourceURLArray[0];
```

What maybe makes this slightly confusing is that the Objective-C counterpart, `NSURL`, *does* need a `*` to make it a pointer as with all Cocoa objects.  So you'd write something like:

```
NSURL *sourceURLArray[10];
...
NSURL *url = sourceURLArray[0];
```

Finally, you might find it easier to use an `NSArray` of `NSURL` objects than using plain C arrays:

```
NSArray *sourceURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
NSURL *url = [sourceURLs objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Excellent answer, Daniel. And here's a little hint that can be helpful generally in situations like this. If you come across a symbol (data type, constant, variable, whatever) you're unfamiliar with, try Command-double-clicking it in the Xcode editor, which will jump you straight to the definition of the symbol.